# How do I prevent window.pageYOffset from resetting on render?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component where I want to change the header based on the `scroll` event. I'm attaching an event handler and based on scroll position and toggling a display class to hide ro show the desired elements.

Where I'm having trouble is, there seems to be some glitchy behavior when my component tries to re render. I have an example in codesandbox below.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      console.log(window.pageYOffset);
      setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [setScrollY]);

  const scrolled = () => scrollY > 40;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={`header ${scrolled() ? "d-none" : ""}`}>Header Main</div>
      <div>
        <div className={`header-secondary ${scrolled() ? "d-none" : ""}`}>
          Header Secondary
        </div>
        <div className={`header-scrolled ${!scrolled() ? "d-none" : ""}`}>
          HeaderScrolled
        </div>

        <div>Scroll Position: {scrollY}</div>
        {[...Array(100)].map((e, i) => (
          <div>
            <div className={scrolled()}>{`SCROLLING`}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My code sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-saha-0oklr

If you notice I have my hide/unhide compnent condition set at 40px. When you scroll slowly around 40px the header will snap back and for some reason the `window.pageYOffset` will reset to  0. I can't figure out why this is?

If you scroll past fast enough it doesn't matter but right around where I toggle the display class there is some odd behavior.

**EDIT**: Updated Example
Effectively what I need to do is have a smmoth transition from `Header Main` to `Header Secondary`. I can't really change styling on `Header Main` because I don't own that part of the product.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about your header. When you are at the top header affects the height of the scrolling body because it is position relative. When you start to scroll down it becomes fixed and leaves the body so it doesn't affect. When you scroll back to top it affect scroll height again.

So there are some tricks to resolve this issue. Giving padding-top: 50px; to scrolling element and using header always fixed will save you.

```
.App {
  padding-top: 50px;
}


.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: teal;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.header-scrolled {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-pine-puunf

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not sure I follow 100%. And my issue unfortunately I can't change the primary header class. I'm limited to changed things in the secondary header for business purposes.